# Set text style in a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a textbox where I have some text. Using 3 Checkboxes I wanna change the style of the text so that if I select underline and bold the text becomes undelined and bold at the same time, but I don't know how to add a style property to the font without changing the previous style. Any idea on how I can do that?
Thanks.

Comment: share some code that you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable one of the font styles:

```
tb.Font = new Font(tb.Font, tb.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
```

To disable one of the font styles:

```
tb.Font = new Font(tb.Font, tb.Font.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold);
```

Both of these will keep the other flags. See the bottom of this answer for why this works.

To set or clear the flag depending on a checkbox, you can use this code style:

```
var style = tb.Font.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold; // first remove it
if (checkbox.Checked)
    style |= FontStyle.Bold;                 // add it if needed
```

In all three examples above, replace `.Bold` with the appropriate style values.

Here's a small [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    var c = new UserControl();
    var chkBold = new CheckBox();
    var chkItalic = new CheckBox();
    var chkUnderline = new CheckBox();
    var tb = new TextBox();
    c.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { chkBold, chkItalic, chkUnderline, tb });

    chkBold.Location = new Point(8, 8);
    chkBold.Text = "Bold";
    chkBold.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var style = tb.Font.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold;
        if (chkBold.Checked)
            style |= FontStyle.Bold;
        tb.Font = new Font(tb.Font, style);
    };

    chkItalic.Location = new Point(8, 32);
    chkItalic.Text = "Italic";
    chkItalic.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var style = tb.Font.Style & ~FontStyle.Italic;
        if (chkItalic.Checked)
            style |= FontStyle.Italic;
        tb.Font = new Font(tb.Font, style);
    };

    chkUnderline.Location = new Point(8, 56);
    chkUnderline.Text = "Underline";
    chkUnderline.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var style = tb.Font.Style & ~FontStyle.Underline;
        if (chkUnderline.Checked)
            style |= FontStyle.Underline;
        tb.Font = new Font(tb.Font, style);
    };

    tb.Location = new Point(8, 80);
    tb.Text = "Try it";

    c.Dump();
}
```

---

### Why does these two tricks work?

The reason these two tricks work is that the [FontStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum is tagged with `Flags` and that signals that the enum is specially constructed to allow for this. Note that the `Flags` attribute is not needed to write the above code, but its presence tells me that it will work.

The reason is that the enum has been set up as a bit by bit value, where each font style is given its own single bit that signals whether the style is present or not.

That means that this:

```
tb.Font = new Font(tb.Font, tb.Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold);
```

*OR*'s in one new bit, setting it to 1, leaving all other bits untouched.

And this:

```
tb.Font = new Font(tb.Font, tb.Font.Style & ~FontStyle.Bold);
```

*AND*'s the font style with the *inverse* of the font style, this might need some explanation.

This:

```
~FontStyle.Bold
```

takes the value, containing 1 bit set to 1, the bit assigned to the Bold style, and negates/inverses the entire value, setting all bits to their opposite value.

This means that all the bits of this will be set, *except* the one assigned to the Bold style.

Then, when we *AND* this with the existing font style value, we effectively remove that bit, and leave all other bits untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //bold checkbox is changed
        if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily,textBox1.Font.Size, ((FontStyle)((FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline))));
        }
        else if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily,textBox1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
    }

    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //unerline checkbox is changed
        if (checkBox1.Checked && checkBox2.Checked)
        {
           textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily,textBox1.Font.Size, ((FontStyle)((FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline))));
        }
        else if (checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font.FontFamily,textBox1.Font.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write css style and apply that class to textbox property `cssClass`

Comment: The question was for Winforms. It wasn't clear that it was, but apparently it is.